# Correct Nginx configuration for Vue PWA

Tags: nginx, vuejs2, progressive-web-apps

I'm using Vue to create a PWA. I initialized it using vue-cli, as following:

```
vue init pwa my-app-name
```

What could be a proper configuration of Nginx for it in production?

Comment: I'm not sure it would need any special setup.

Comment: @JohnHalsey not even for the cache?